# EnvDTE: How to find if a property is marked as virtual

Tags: t4, envdte

I am putting together a template for creating buddy classes for classes generated by the Entity Framework -> Reverse Engineer Code First context menu item.

I really don't want to include the navigation properties that are marked as virtual.  So how, using CodeProperty interface (or other EnvDTE code) discover if a property is marked as virtual?

To say it with pseudo code:

```
<# foreach (CodeElement ce in classInFile.Members)
        { 
            if (ce.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementProperty && [ce not marked as virtual]) 
            {
                WriteDisplayName(ce); 
                WriteProperty(ce);
                WriteLine("");
            }
        } #>
```

Ie, how do I determine that ce is not marked as virtual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the CodeElement to a [CodeProperty2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.codeproperty2.aspx) and check its [OverrideKind property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.codeproperty2.overridekind.aspx).

Comment: that sounds correct, but I have had a conflict with the Tangible T4 library I am using when I try to use EnvDTE80, so shied off.  I will have another look at why that conflict happened.  I am pretty sure your answer is the correct answer, so have voted it up and marked it (provisionally) as the answer.  Thanks.